# SQL error: "operator does not exist: character varying = bigint"

Tags: sql, datatable, bigint

I am trying to retrieve SQL information about the singers and their number of songs, selecting only singers with at least 2 songs, and ordering records by the number of songs in groups starting with the biggest one. I keep getting this error:

> operator does not exist: character varying = bigint

My code:

```sql
SELECT * FROM songs
WHERE title = (SELECT COUNT(title) FROM songs)
GROUP BY singer
HAVING COUNT(title) >=2
ORDER BY singer, title DESC;
```

Can someone help?

Comment: It's a good idea to tag your question with the specific database (sql is a generic term).

Comment: What `where title = (select count(title) from ... )` is intended to mean? Mote, that you cannot use `group by` with `select *`, because columns not present in `group by` should be aggregated using some aggregate function. You need to check the syntax in the documentation of your DBMS.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you are comparing a title (varchar) with a count (bigint), which makes no sense. Try this:

```sql
SELECT * FROM songs
GROUP BY singer
HAVING COUNT(title) >= 2
ORDER BY singer, COUNT(title) DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this error because I was using single quotes, not double. Misleading wording on the error, but simple fix.

```
SELECT * FROM app.user WHERE id = "abd-123";
```

^ did not work. I needed:

```
SELECT * FROM app.user WHERE id = 'abd-123';
```

Easy.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT singer, COUNT(title) no_of_songs FROM songs
GROUP BY singer
HAVING COUNT(title) >= 2
ORDER BY singer, no_of_songs DESC

or 
SELECT singer, COUNT(title) no_of_songs FROM songs
GROUP BY singer
HAVING COUNT(title) >= 2
ORDER BY singer, COUNT(title) DESC
```

when you use group by, column names used in select statements must be in group statement except for aggrigate function
refer this https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp